Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (PyQt6-sip)
    pip install PyQt6
    Collecting PyQt6
    Using cached PyQt6-6.7.1-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.1 kB)
    Collecting PyQt6-sip<14,>=13.8 (from PyQt6)
    Using cached PyQt6_sip-13.8.0.tar.gz (92 kB)
    Installing build dependencies ... done
    Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
    Collecting PyQt6-Qt6<6.8.0,>=6.7.0 (from PyQt6)
    Using cached PyQt6_Qt6-6.7.3-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (551 bytes)
    Using cached PyQt6-6.7.1-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.6 MB)
    Using cached PyQt6_Qt6-6.7.3-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (58.5 MB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: PyQt6-sip
    Building wheel for PyQt6-sip (pyproject.toml) ... error
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error`your text`

    × Building wheel for PyQt6-sip (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [5 lines of output]
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running build_ext
        building 'PyQt6.sip' extension
        error: Unable to find a compatible Visual Studio installation.
        [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyQt6-sip
    Failed to build PyQt6-sip
    ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (PyQt6-sip)

My Python version 3.13.0
I had alrealy try to update my pip.
I think i already install  Visual Studio installation
enter image description here

Please read about the recommendation about not uploading images of code/data/errors. This is also valid for dialogs and message boxes showing text that is not in English language or contains characters used in non-Latin writing languages: you may still leave the image, but at least provide a translation of its text, don't expect us to translate it.

The issue lies in the .whl file creation for PyQt6-sip in Python 3.13. Let me explain the root cause and why this error occurs.
When you run pip install PyQt6 in the terminal, pip starts resolving and installing all the required dependencies of PyQt6, one of which is PyQt6-sip. The installation process typically uses .whl files (binary distribution format for Python packages). If no pre-built .whl file is available for your system and Python version, pip attempts to build the file from source. Unfortunately, with Python 3.13, this build process fails.
Here are the possible reasons for this failure:

C API Changes: Python 3.13's C API may include changes that break compatibility with extensions or build scripts used by PyQt6-sip.
Toolchain Updates: New Python versions often require updated versions of build tools like setuptools, wheel, or compilers to handle changes in the Python ecosystem.
Library Maintainers: The maintainers of PyQt6-sip may not have updated their library yet to support Python 3.13, especially given the complexity of native extensions like this.
To resolve this issue, I recommend using an older Python version (e.g., 3.12.7), which I verified works for this package. Python 3.12 is well-supported by most libraries and avoids the compatibility challenges associated with Python 3.13.


Thank you !  I used the old version Python and PyQt was succesfully installed.
